# Circle text with jquery animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have tried circle texts with Jquery animation. My working fiddle is:

http://jsfiddle.net/60rz99zu/5/

```
$(function () {
$('.main-content').circleType({radius: 1000});

    var $els = $('div[id^=quote]'),
        i = 0,
        len = $els.length;
        $els.slice(1).hide();
        setInterval(function () {
            $els.eq(i).fadeOut(function () {
            i = (i + 1) % len
            $els.eq(i).fadeIn();
        })
    }, 2000)
})
```

The first text is working good.  See my second and third text. The circle effect is messed. I spent more time to fix. I couldn't. How can i achieve this??

Comment: r u looking this? http://jsfiddle.net/60rz99zu/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is since those elements are hidden, the circle plugin is not able to findout its dimensions properly.

So one solution is to hide them after initiazing the library

```
<div id="quote1" class="text-center main-content">First Text here</div>
<div id="quote2" class="text-center main-content">Second Text here</div>
<div id="quote3" class="text-center main-content">Third text here</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/o0r357ec/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Working goooood.

Answer (score 2):

remove the `style="display:none"` on the second and third text. You dont't need it cause the javascript also hides the elements.